# How To Pull Firebase Data Into A Variable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently learning Firebase and Android Studios. I'm trying to pull data from my firebase into specific variables.

This is the code in specific I'm confused about, I understand the code I'm just not sure how to make setUserName be stored in moverName.

```
  private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        moverInfo mInfo = new moverInfo();
        mInfo.setUserName(ds.child(userID).getValue(moverInfo.class).getUserName()); //set & get the name
        mInfo.setLicense(ds.child(userID).getValue(moverInfo.class).getLicense()); //set & get license number
        mInfo.setVehReg(ds.child(userID).getValue(moverInfo.class).getVehReg()); //set & get veh reg

        //String moverName = dataSnapshot.getValue(moverInfo.class).setUserName();

    }
}
```

I'm trying to set the userName pulled into moverName which is an empty variable that is attached to my gui.

Comment: Something like `String moverName =  mInfo.getUserName()` ?

Comment: Add your database structure and tell which values do you need to retrieve, I can help you write a code for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
moverInfo mInfo = ds.getValue(moverInfo.class)
```

if you have the same variable names in Firebase as in your moverInfo POJO class your model will be filled correctly.

Comment: Where do I add this line? Below the code shown where the // is or replace certain code?